# Помогите с отступом ListView для отображения массива картинок

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml, ui

Собственно для отображения массива картинок используется **ListView** с **WrapPanel**. Картинки представляют собой нарезанные квадраты *"тайлов"* из List-а в вью модели.
В DataTemplate используется только один элемент Image.

Проблема в том, что ListView заполняется не полностью и получается большой отступ от скроллбара. Вот это отступа нужно избавиться.

Проблема наглядно:

[image: отступ]

Страшный XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="TileGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding TileSet}" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel  
                Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"
                       ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
                       MinWidth="{Binding ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                       ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Tile}" Width="32" Height="32"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Так же код заполнения массива на всякий случай:

```
public void LoadTileSet()
{
    const int tileSize = 32; //Временно для теста
    var tileMapTextute = new BitmapImage(new Uri("BaseTileSet.png", UriKind.Relative));

    var textureSizeX = (int)tileMapTextute.Height;
    var textureSizeY = (int)tileMapTextute.Width;

    var maxX = textureSizeX / tileSize;
    var maxY = textureSizeY / tileSize;

    for (var y = 0; y != maxY - 1; y++)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x != maxX - 1; x++)
        {
            var tile = new TileImage(
                new CroppedBitmap(tileMapTextute, new Int32Rect(x * tileSize, y * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize)), x, y);
            TileSet.Add(tile);
        }
    }
}
```

Что бы по быстрому воспроизвести у себя:

```
<ListView x:Name="TileGrid" SelectionMode="Single"  Width="200" 
Height="300">
    <ListView.Items>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="32" Height="32"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Width="32" Height="32"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="32" Height="32"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Width="32" Height="32"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="32" Height="32"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Width="32" Height="32"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="32" Height="32"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Width="32" Height="32"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="32" Height="32"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Width="32" Height="32"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="32" Height="32"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Width="32" Height="32"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="32" Height="32"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Width="32" Height="32"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="32" Height="32"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Width="32" Height="32"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="32" Height="32"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Width="32" Height="32"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="32" Height="32"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Width="32" Height="32"/>
    </ListView.Items>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel  
                Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"
                ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
                MinWidth="{Binding ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Comment: А если у `WrapPanel` убрать все эти привязки? Пусть она сама растягивается как ей нужно.

Comment: Вы можете такой пример предоставить, чтобы я у себя без лишнего додумывания мог запустить и увидеть проблему (можно без картинок, например, с Border'ами фиксированной ширины/высоты)?

Comment: @Андрей NOP Сделал, везде работать должно. Просто встройте в Grid c auto.

Comment: Отступ всё таки не от скроллбара так то.

Comment: Так и не понял в чем суть вопроса, вы хотите, чтобы вертикальный скроллбар был вплотную к крайнему справа ряду элементов или что?

Comment: @Андрей NOP Да, так

Comment: Если никто не ответит раньше — завтра утром напишу ответ.

Comment: Предполагаю, что придется писать свою панель. Только вот пока не понятно, ну сдвинется скроллбар влево, но это пустое место тогда будет справа от него. Что с ним делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел перебором простой вариант. Нужно задать свойство BorderThickness="0" для ListView и это устранит отступ.

Comment: Что-то с трудом верится